# How to query Firestore for user's name based on their email in Flutter chat app with Firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I'm building a chat app using Flutter and Firebase, and I'm having trouble displaying the sender's name correctly in the chat messages.

On the registration screen, I'm storing the user's name in a Firestore collection called 'userNames' like this:

```
final newUser = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
await _firestore.instance.collection('userNames').add({'name': userName});
if (newUser != null && password.length >= 6) {
  Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, 'chat');
}
```

When the user sends a new message on the Chat screen, I'm storing the message data in a Firestore collection called 'messages' like this:

```
await _fireStore.collection('messages').add({
  'Text': messageText,
  'Sender': FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.email,
  'Time': DateTime.now(),
});
```

**I want to display the sender's name instead of their email address in the chat messages. So in the message collection, I am trying to send the current user's name which I stored previously instead of the user's email.**

Thank you in advance for any help or suggestions you can provide to help me solve this issue. Your expertise and guidance are greatly appreciated!

To do this I tried it in this way, However, this doesn't seem to work.

```
final currentUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;
final userNamesSnapshot = await _firestore.instance.collection('userNames').where('email', isEqualTo: currentUser.email).get();
final userName = userNamesSnapshot.docs.first.get('name');

await _fireStore.collection('messages').add({
  'Text': messageText,
  'Sender': userName,
  'Time': DateTime.now(),
});
```

Comment: "this doesn't seem to work" is hard to help with. It's more likely someone can help if you debug the code locally, and report the results in your question. So If you set a breakpoint on each line of the code you shared, run the code in a debugger, and then check the value of each variable on each line, which is the **first** line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: If you're new to this: the Android docs have a great page on [debugging your app](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug) to get you started with, including the section on [working with breakpoints](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug#breakPoints) and [inspecting varialbles](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug#variablesAndWatches).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding the user name to the `userNames` collection in Firestore, I recommend you update the [User](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/User-class.html) object by calling [updateDisplayName()](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/User/updateDisplayName.html). Now, when you  want to send a new message, you can simply use:

```
await _fireStore.collection('messages').add({
  'Text': messageText,
  'Sender': FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.displayName,
  //                                               
  'Time': DateTime.now(),
});
```

The benefit of this approach is that you'll don't have to pay for a write operation in Firestore. Reading and updating a User object in the Firebase Authentication is free of charge.

Comment: It did exactly what I was looking for, While doing this I observed some more options like PhotoURL, how does that work ? Can I store user's profile picture using PhotoURL?

Comment: Yes, you can also store the `photoURL` in the same object. Again, the addition and the read of the User object is free of charge,